# Question about .gesture(drag gesture) in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, drag

I am trying to detect when this text view has been swiped on.  The code compiles fine, but I am not able to trigger the swipe on my actual device.  When I swipe, nothing happens.  Tap seems to work just fine.  Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong in my code?

In case this matters, I'm developing a watch OS app in swift 5.3 with the latest Xcode.

```
var body: some View {

    Text(tempstring).onTapGesture { checkStateRoll() }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global)
     .onEnded { value in
                            let horizontalAmount = value.translation.width as CGFloat
                            let verticalAmount = value.translation.height as CGFloat
                            
                            if abs(horizontalAmount) > abs(verticalAmount) {
                                horizontalAmount < 0 ? leftswipe() : rightswipe()
                            } else {
                                verticalAmount < 0 ? upswipe() : downswipe()
                            }
                            tempstring = String(numdice) + "d" + String(typesofdice[typedice])
                            speaknumber()
                        }        ) 
    
    .background(progstate == 2 ? Color.blue : Color.red)
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help. This has been stumping me for weeks.

Comment: I would try to put the drag gesture task as the first modifier and the on tap gesture as the second one. Sometimes the modifier hierarchy matters. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. With respect to layout, setting a frame will no change the text size because the text sizes itself to its content.  Use a greedy view like a ZStack if you want to take up all of the space.
2. The sequence of the modifiers does matter.  You read the order in which they are applied from bottom to top, so in this case they need to go on the stack.

Here is an example playground:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct V: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.red
      Text("Test")
    }
      .onTapGesture { print("tap") }
      .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global).onEnded { print($0)})

  }
}

let host = UIHostingController(rootView: V().frame(width: 500.0, height: 500.0))
host.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = host
```

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. In the end, the issue was the fact that I was trying to drag the text frame itself, when what I really wanted was to be able to swipe anywhere on the screen.  Adding a ZStack around it, and applying the drag code on the ZStack, worked wonders.  Now the drag function is working as expected, and my code is done!! Once I get a few more non-coding related files (sound files *grumble grumble*) I'll be ready for release!  Thanks for all the help!